# Sum of values with references on different rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I want to sum specific values in column F, provided that the respective values in columns C and E have a unique match in columns O and Q. To make the logic easier, I would like to include a condition that the summing occurs only if the date in column B is before June 30, 2023.

I will give an example: in this case, I would like to sum the values in column F for all matches of "Pinco-fruit" in columns O and Q. So the result I expect is 8.

One last important thing: I need the whole operation to be performed with one formula. I have tried different combinations of SUMIFS, VLOOKUP, FILTER, ARRAYFORMULA, but I have not found the right one.

Thanks for the help!

| B | C | ... | E | F | ... | O | ... | Q |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9/3/22 | Pinco | ... | Apple | 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 9/3/22 | Pinco | ... | Banana | 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 9/3/22 | Pinco | ... | Kiwi | 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 6/30/23 |  |  |  |  |  | Pinco | ... | Apple |
| 6/30/23 |  |  |  |  |  | Pinco | ... | Banana |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `match()`, like this:

```
=sum(filter(F1:F, match(C1:C, O1:O, 0), match(E1:E, Q1:Q, 0)))
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378).